# Windows.System.User events not being raised in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, prism

I am trying to have some logic when Windows user is being changed while my UWP app is running and for that in my OnLaunchApplicationAsync method I have:

```
        var userWatcher = Windows.System.User.CreateWatcher();

        userWatcher.AuthenticationStatusChanged += AuthenticationStatusChanged;
```

and I also have

```
        private void AuthenticationStatusChanged(Windows.System.UserWatcher sender, Windows.System.UserChangedEventArgs args)
        {
          // Some logic
        }
```

But the problem is that when I log off with my current user and sign in with another one, the expected event is not being raised.

I have also tried out `userWatcher.Updated` for updating user data as well as `userWatcher.AuthenticationStatusChanging` with the same result.

Am I doing this in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the watcher, otherwise these events are not fired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I do that I get:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)`

Comment: @n.shojaei from which line?

Comment: > first add the event handlers, then start the watcher.

Comment: From the start method. I did it the exact way. Maybe it's something to do with Prism that I am using for UWP @kennyzx

Comment: Based on MSDN I `You must add a handler for the UserWatcher.Added before event before calling Start.`
[System_UserWatcher_Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userwatcher.start#Windows_System_UserWatcher_Start)